# how to stop angular redirecting automatically to default page (defined with otherwise method) even with a VALID route

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angular-routing

I'm sending an email with a link to an invitation, but I'm having trouble with the link attached in the email which something is like `myapp.com/#/invitation/J5QSXr9/token/J6ixelV3`. When I click on it, it always redirects automatically to my default page `myapp.com/#/login` which is undesired. What is really weird is that when I click back on the browser it shows correctly the web page. What I have defined in route provider is this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["firebase"]).config(

['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl:'partials/login.html', controller:'LoginCtrl'});
        $routeProvider.when('/todos', {templateUrl:'partials/todos-list.html', controller:'TodosListCtrl', authRequired:true, pathTo: '/todos'});
        $routeProvider.when('/todos/:todosId', {templateUrl:'partials/todos-detail.html', controller:'TodoCtrl', authRequired:true});
        $routeProvider.when('/invitation/:todosId/token/:tokenNum', {templateUrl:'partials/invitation.html', controller:'InvitationCtrl', authRequired:false});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:'/login'});
    }]
)

// establish authentication
.run(['angularFireAuth', '$rootScope', function(angularFireAuth, $rootScope) {
  var url="https://myapp.firebaseio.com/";
  angularFireAuth.initialize(url, {scope: $rootScope, name: "user", path:"/login"});

}]);
```

You will notice that I'm using angular `$routeProvider` to do this, and also i'm using Firebase and angularFire, and in order to make the authentication i'm using `angularFireAuth` ( [like the one described in here by Anant](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/D6wgBgUtK94/AygqI4oJ7b4J) ). So the route with `/invitation/:todosId/token/:tokenNum` should not ask for authentication, notice that I set `authRequired:false` so any one can access to it, but it constantly redirects to `/login`. What seems weird is that the browser history shows the page, so when i click back on the browser the page shows and works correctly.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: have you tried removing the `authRequired` parameters completely? Its hard to tell if the issue is the authentication piece of if you're routes themselves are not configured properly... by removing authentication (temporarily just for testing), you could narrow the issue down and figure out if authentication has anything to do with it.  I've never actually used `angularFire` so i don't know much about how it authenticates.

Comment: Good idea, but when I remove the `authRequired` parameters the problem persists, but when I remove the last line `angularFireAuth.initialize(...)` the route "/invitation/:todosId/token/:tokenNum" works properly, so definitely the problem is related with `angularFireAuth` or the `$routeProvider`

Comment: I copied this code down locally, used it with angular 1.0.8, angularFire 0.3 (from the cdn) and could not repro the issue by any means other than using an invalid URL (such as `#/invitation/J5QSXr9/token` vs `#/invitation/J5QSXr9/token/J6ixelV3`). I did note that even with a bad URL I could bypass the error by providing a pathTo in the .when(...) object, which may or may not be helpful for troubleshooting where the error lies.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve it this way. On the `angularFire.js` file when `new FirebaseSimpleLogin` is called (on line 440 or so), I noticed that it calls `self._loggedOut()` after loading the page and not having a valid login, so I decided (** *arbitrarily***) to only call this when redirect is required so added the condition `if ($route.current.authRequired)` the result is this:

```
[...]
var client = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(this._ref, function(err, user) {
  self._cb(err, user);
  if (err) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("angularFireAuth:error", err);
  } else if (user) {
    self._loggedIn(user)
  } else {
    if ($route.current.authRequired)
      self._loggedOut();
  }
});
this._authClient = client;
[...]
```

Hope someone could explain better why this is needed...